How to render Hebrew fonts in an .rdl generated pdf
My .rdl report is uploaded to dynamics 365.  On the report preview, it's the correct font, as chosen in visual studio.  When that's exported to pdf, it converts it to microsoft sans serif, which looks terrible with Hebrew.
I have tried adobe fonts, google fonts, all converting to microsoft on pdf.  when i download the report to word, the correct font appears.
Anyone know how i can get a good Hebrew font to appear in the pdf export of an .rdl? I've tried also editing the font files to be embedable with font forge, but i wasn't sucessful.
